# Projectile motion derivation from a book that I don't understand

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile

I was going through a first year physics book and came across a derivation I don't understand.

[image]

So first the book gives you an equation using ${x=x_0+v_0t+\frac{1}{2}at^2}$

$z(x)=-\frac{1}{2} \frac{g}{v_{0x}^2}x^2+\frac{v_{oz}}{v_{ox}}x+h$ which still makes sense because obviously the author plugged in $t=\frac{t}{v_{ox}}$

after this the book says if you wanna calculate the highest point of the curve, use $\frac{dz}{dx}=0$ which we then have $$x_s=\frac{v_{ox}v_{oz}}{g}=\frac{v_0^2}{2g} \cdot\sin2\phi$$

To this point I still easily follow.

but then the author says in order to calculate the furthers effective range, plug in $z(x_w)=0$

$$x_w=\frac{v_{ox}v_{oz}}{g} \pm \left\{\left(\frac{v_{ox}v_{oz}}{g}\right)^2+\frac{2v_{0x}^2}{g}\cdot h\right\}^{1/2}$$

Here is where i'm fuzzy....Where does this come from, i tried different things but i don't know what the author is trying to do.

The first part of the equation $x_w=\frac{v_{ox}v_{oz}}{g}$ is for $x_s$ which is the highest point, then plus or minus the rest? And the first part of the equation inside the second part is again $x_w=\frac{v_{ox}v_{oz}}{g}$ which is $x_s$?

I mean I can derive the equation myself, it is not very difficult. But I just don't understand how the author did it...If someone could clear that up would be great!!

Comment: This equation ${x=x_0+v_0t+\frac{1}{2}at^2}$ is wrong

Comment: It is the solution to the quadratic $0=-\frac{1}{2} \frac{g}{v_{0x}^2}x^2+\frac{v_{oz}}{v_{ox}}x+h$ enabling you to find the range if you know the initial components of the velocity of projection.

Comment: @Eli makes sense to me, $x_0$ is the initial position wrt to the origin/frame of reference and ${v_0t+\frac{1}{2}at^2}$ is the displacement and ofcourse you count the signs positive and negative then $x$ gives the final position wrt to the origin

Answer (score 2):

Look at your graph where the path crosses the $x$-axis. This happens at the point $\left( x_w , 0 \right)$. Since at $x_w$, the projectile's height $z$ must be zero, you can find $x_w$ by solving the equation $z\left( x_w\right)=0$ for $x_w$.

You simply apply the quadratic formula to the $$z\left( x_w\right)=0 \quad\implies\quad-\frac{1}{2} \frac{g}{v_{0x}^2}x_w^2+\frac{v_{oz}}{v_{ox}}x_w+h=0$$ equation, and after some simplifications, $$x_w=\frac{v_{ox}v_{oz}}{g} \pm \sqrt{ \left(\frac{v_{ox}v_{oz}}{g}\right)^2+\frac{2hv_{0x}^2}{g}}$$ is what you get.

Answer (score 1):

If $z=0$

$$-\frac{1}{2} \frac{g}{v_{0x}^2}x_w^2+\frac{v_{oz}}{v_{ox}}x_w+h=0$$

multiply through by $-2v_{0x}^2$ to get $$gx_w^2-2v_{ox}{v_{oz}}x_w-2hv_{0x}^2=0$$

then solve using the quadratic formula for a quadratic of the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$

$$x = \frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$